# pagination without dataprovider

Tags: view, pagination, yii2

Hi i tried to used pagination without dataProvider. Can I used this like:

```
 public function actionShowtest($id){
      $model = $this->findModel($id);
      $messages= \common\models\PrMessage::find()->where(['Rel_Dialog'=>$id])->all();
      $count = count($messages);
      $pagination = new Pagination(['totalCount' => $count, 'pageSize'=>10]);
        return $this->render('messages', [
                'model' => $model,
                'messages'=>$messages,
                'pagination'=>$pagination
            ]);
    }
```

And in my view:

```
<?php echo \yii\widgets\LinkPager::widget([
    'pagination' => $pagination,
]); ?>
```

My $count return me :

> int 12

and in my view i can see pagination with 1,2 but it not work becosue it show me all 12 records but I want to see this 10 records. I have 2 buttons of page but it still show me all records. What can I do to fix that?

my view:

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\DetailView;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use yii\widgets\ListView;
/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model common\models\BlogPost */
$this->title = $model->Id;
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => Yii::t('app', 'Konwersacje'), 'url' => ['index']];
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;

?>
<div class="blog-post-view">
<?php foreach($model->prMessages as $msg): ?>

  <?=$msg->relSender->Name.' '.$msg->relSender->Surname;  ?>
  <?=$msg->CreatedAt; ?>
  <?=$msg->Text; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>

</div>
<?php echo \yii\widgets\LinkPager::widget([
    'pagination' => $pagination,
]); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its becoz Your $messages variable contains all values , its not being limited according to your pagination

Try This

```
public function actionShowtest($id){
  $model = $this->findModel($id);
  $messagesQuery = \common\models\PrMessage::find()->where(['Rel_Dialog'=>$id]);
  $pagination = new Pagination(['totalCount' => $messagesQuery->count(), 'pageSize'=>10]);
  $messages = $messagesQuery->offset($messagesQuery->offset)
            ->limit($pagination->limit)
            ->all();
  return $this->render('messages', [
            'model' => $model,
            'messages'=>$messages,
            'pagination'=>$pagination
  ]);
}
```

Comment: there is still the same

Comment: So even after we gave `->limit($pagination->limit)` your first page renders 12 items ?

Comment: sure i updete my post

Comment: please replace $model->prMessages by $messages in foreach Loop

Comment: then i have trying to get property of non obiect:<?=$msg->relSender->Name.' '.$msg->relSender->Surname;  ?> on all $msg

Comment: For the time being remove  `<?=$msg->relSender->Name.' '.$msg->relSender->Surname;  ?>` from the view and check if pagination is working. If so we can give null check to remove the error.